# Cross-validation: finding row indices for a test set that aren't part of a training set

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, machine-learning, cross-validation

What I need to do is randomly pick (with replacement) 50 rows from a numpy matrix for the purposes of training a linear separator.

Then, I need to test the linear separator using the rows which I did not pick.

For the first part, where `A` is my full data matrix, I do:

```
A_train = A[np.random.randint(A.shape[0],size=50),:]
```

But I currently have no effective way to find:

```
A_test = ...
```

Where `A_test` contains no rows that are the same as `A_train`.   How would I do this?

**Key to this problem is that `A` is an n x m matrix, and not a 1-dimensional matrix...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.setdiff1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) to find row indices that are not included in your training set:

```
import numpy as np

gen = np.random.RandomState(0)

n_total = 1000
n_train = 800

train_idx = gen.choice(n_total, size=n_train)
test_idx = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(n_total), train_idx)
```

One consequence of sampling with replacement is that the number of examples eligible for inclusion in the test set will vary according to the number of repeated examples in the training set:

```
print(test_idx.size)
# 439
```

If you want to ensure that the size of the test set is consistent, you could resample with replacement from the set of indices that aren't in the training set:

```
n_test = 200
test_idx2 = gen.choice(test_idx, size=n_test)
```

If you don't actually care about sampling with replacement then a simpler option would be to generate a random permutation of all the indices, then take the first N as training examples and the rest as test examples:

```
idx = gen.permutation(n_total)
train_idx, test_idx = idx[:n_train], idx[n_train:]
```

Or you could just shuffle the rows of your array in place using `np.random.shuffle`.

---

I should also point out that scikit-learn has [various convenience methods](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation-iterators) for partitioning data into training and test sets for the purposes of cross-validation.

Comment: Ah, ok, I will check out scipy.  I have to do a 10-fold cross validation later. 

At this point, consistent size of A_test is unimportant, since I only do it once to produce an error metric and a few images.  Then I do 10-fold cross.  The first dataset I use has ~80 samples, so, IMHO, a random subset of 50, without replacement, is statistically insignificant...so I might as well just partition it at 50 as do it without replacement...

Comment: I have leeway in the assignment to make that kind of choice.  Anyhow, thanks for the heads up.   And the pointer to scipy...